# angular ag-grid event that notifies that all of the cacheblock items are loaded

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using SSRM ag-grid, and I have data that should be displayed in groups and the groups should be expanded.
I'm using pagination with route query parameters in my ag-grid `app-path/component-path?pageNum=2`
and then onInit I get the data for the first page, because otherwise the first page's data won't be available. (already tried it).
after loading the first page, I want to go to the page in the query param using the grid's API `paginationGoToPage(param)`.

the issue is, not all of the groups data is loaded fully before moving to the next page, and then when I navigate back to the first page using navigation buttons I see that not all the groups' data is loaded, and since it's cached it won't be loaded again.

my current solution is to use `setTimeout` to check every 100 ms if the cacheBlock is fully loaded for the first page, and only then moving to the query param's page.

I wanted to know if there's a specific event that can help me get this data and move to the page when all of the cacheblock items are fully loaded.

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: @robert there's a lot of code and I don't really think it's relevant, since I don't have an issue in my code - it's working. I just was an event that would notify me about something.